# Write text in orange with Write-Host

Tags: powershell, write-host

I'm wondering if it's possible to write some coloured-text in **orange** with `Write-Host` (or with another PowerShell Cmdlet).

It seems `Orange` is not an available color for the `-ForegroundColor` parameter, but commands like `Write-Warning` are able to display something in orange.

Comment: Try DarkYellow, however for me this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Keep in mind that using a specific color could cause problems, because you can't make assumptions about the user's background color, so you can end up with something unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Found what appears to be Write-Host code here:
[Powershell-Misc/Write-Host.ps1 at master · beatcracker/Powershell-Misc · GitHub](https://github.com/beatcracker/Powershell-Misc/blob/master/Write-Host.ps1)

Found ANSI escape codes here:
[ANSI escape code - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Found color orange here: [RGB Color Codes Chart](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html)

Built this code based on info taken from the above:

```
$Esc = [char]27
$Ansi24BitTemplate = "$Esc[{0};2;{1};{2};{3}m"
$Ansi24BitFore = '38'
$Ansi24BitBack = '48'
$OrangeForeColor = $Ansi24BitTemplate -f $Ansi24BitFore, 255, 165, 0
$OrangeBackColor = $Ansi24BitTemplate -f $Ansi24BitBack, 255, 165, 0

Write-Host "$($OrangeBackColor)Testing" -ForegroundColor Black
Write-Host "$($OrangeForeColor)Testing" -BackgroundColor Black
```

Which gave this output:

[image]

NOTE: This will not work on some older equipment and in some situations.  But I believe it will work in the majority of Windows 10 computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the PowerShell colors via the registry at HKCU\Console in the ColorTable00-ColorTable15 keys. There are only sixteen colors available though, so you will have to replace a color that is already assigned with the color you want. You would then use the original name in your write-host.

**WARNING: This is untested and may affect the colors on other consoles!**